# Existence of "simd reduction(:)" In GCC and MSVC?

Tags: visual-c++, gcc, vectorization, simd, icc

simd pragma can be used with icc compiler to perform a reduction operator:

```
#pragma simd
#pragma simd reduction(+:acc)
#pragma ivdep
for(int i( 0 ); i < N; ++i )
{
  acc += x[i];
}
```

Is there any equivalent solution in msvc or/and gcc?

Ref(p28): http://d3f8ykwhia686p.cloudfront.net/1live/intel/CompilerAutovectorizationGuide.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GCC definitely can vectorize. Suppose you have file reduc.c with contents:

```
int foo(int *x, int N)
  {
    int acc, i;

    for( i = 0; i < N; ++i )
      {
        acc += x[i];
      }

    return acc;
  }
```

Compile it (I used gcc 4.7.2) with command line:

```
$ gcc -O3 -S reduc.c -ftree-vectorize -msse2
```

Now you can see vectorized loop in assembler.

Also you may switch on verbose vectorizer output say with

```
$ gcc -O3 -S reduc.c -ftree-vectorize -msse2 -ftree-vectorizer-verbose=1
```

Now you will get console report:

```
Analyzing loop at reduc.c:5
Vectorizing loop at reduc.c:5
5: LOOP VECTORIZED.
reduc.c:1: note: vectorized 1 loops in function.
```

[Look at the official docs](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/tree-ssa/vectorization.html) to better understand cases where GCC can and cannot vectorize.

Comment: sorry, I missed this: "To enable vectorization of floating point reductions use -ffast-math or -fassociative-math."

Answer (score 3):

For Visual Studio 2012:
With options `/O1 /O2/GL`, to report vectorization use `/Qvec-report:(1/2)`

```
int s = 0; 
for ( int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i ) 
{ 
s += A[i]; // vectorizable 
}
```

In the case of reductions over "`float`" or "`double`" types, vectorization requires that the `/fp:fast` switch is thrown. This is because vectorizing the reduction operation depends upon "floating point reassociation". Reassociation is only allowed when `/fp:fast` is thrown

> Ref(associated doc;p12) http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nativeconcurrency/archive/2012/07/10/auto-vectorizer-in-visual-studio-11-cookbook.aspx

Answer (score 1):

gcc requires -ffast-math to enable this optimization (as mentioned in the reference given above), regardless of use of #pragma omp simd reduction.
icc is becoming less reliant on pragma for this optimization (except that /fp:fast is needed in absence of pragma), but the extra ivdep and simd pragmas in the original post are undesirable.  icc may do bad things when given a pragma simd which doesn't include all relevant reduction, firstprivate, and lastprivate clauses (and gcc may break with -ffast-math, particularly in combination with -march or -mavx).
msvc 2012/2013 are very limited in auto-vectorization.  There are no simd reductions, no vectorization within OpenMP parallel regions, no vectorization of conditionals, and no advantage is taken of __restrict in vectorizations (there is some run-time check to vectorize less efficiently but safely without __restrict).

Comment: The combination gcc -fopenmp -march=native -funsafe-math-optimizations -O3 fails for me.  If I remove any of those 3 options or cut back to -march=corei7 or -O2, the case succeeds.  -march=native is much more aggressive for avx and avx2 architectures, so its influence may not be a total surprise.

Comment: I think it's documented somewhere that -O3 -ffast-math is required for some of these optimizations, so it's not surprising that -ffast-math isn't so risky with -O2.

Comment: In the benchmark posted to https://github.com/tprince/lcd I split the C source files into those which need -ffast-math and those which need -fopenmp.  For various Intel compilers I use the same options throughout for each source language.

Comment: The problem of conflict between -fopenmp and -ffast-math showed up with g++ as well, on a Westmere platform, solved similarly.  The C++ build is set up for MSVC as well.